# Вещание музыки с Android

Tags: android

Здравствуйте. Хочу реализовать возможность вещания музыки.

Объясню подробнее. Есть ли возможность взять музыку, играющую в плеере стандартном, или в своём, сделать m3u файл, отправить куда нибудь на сервер его. И сделать так, что бы тот кто запустит этот файл у себя, смог слушать муызку, запущенную на первом устройстве? Что то вроде Радио должно получится.

Если не понятно расписал, спрашивайте, объясню по подробнее.

**Что я хочу увидеть в ответе:**
 - Возможно ли это в целом;
 - пример подобной реализации;
 - другие полезные советы.)

Спасибо всем заранее

Comment: Для начала хочу задать вопрос. У вас на девайсе будет белый ip? Тот, кто должен будет "слушать", точно до вас сможет достучаться?

Comment: нет. Но это и не требуется. Девай отправляется все на облако. А "Слушатели" в свою очередь, тянут все с облако. т.к если тянуть напрямую с девайся, то для 2,3 и т.д слушателей просто нехватит ширины канала.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Если предположить, что вся музыка будет в "облаке" (или как минимум сдублирована туда), тогда задача достаточно проста. В последнем google I/O показывали пример с двумя таймерами на разный устройствах.

как организовать. У клиентом может быть стандарный плеер, им не нужно ничего знать о деталях реализации. На управляющем устройстве нужно свой клиент.
Клиент время от времени передает на сервер следующие песни, которые нужно проиграть и время (это опорный момент), когда их нужно играть.  Если управляющий меняет плейлист (добавил/удалил/поменял порядок), то нужно на сервер эту информацию отправить.

В последней реализации GMC (то есть пуша) добавили "обратый пуш", который сильно упрощает данную задачу.

На серверной части можно взять к примеру [icecast.org](http://icecast.org). Для него есть библиотеки (к примеру на [php](http://phpshout.sourceforge.net/)), которые помогут манипулировать плейлистом.

Comment: Спасибо. Этот вариант один из подходящих. 
Но есть другая проблема... Возможно потребуется добавить Голос "Начитатать" какую - то речь. Так что удобнее было бы передавать это каким то Потоком.

Comment: Если только не нужен "прямой эфир", то можно записать "речь" и отправить на сервер. А сервер вставит ее в список на воспроизведение.

Comment: Вот скорее всего "Прямой эфир" и нужен. Такого плана реализация возможна?

Comment: да, конечно. Правда не знаю, получится ли это с icecast.

Answer (score 0):

Есть вариант реализации задумки, если сделать из Android телефона [UPnP](http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/UPnP) или [DLNA](http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/DLNA) сервер.

В Google Play достаточно таких приложений: [тынц](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.icecoldapps.dlnaserver) или [сюда](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=es.mediaserverpro)

Если писать самому - другой вопрос, только зачем?

Comment: Спасибо. Задача стоит не заработать денег на готовом приложение. А Набраться опыта в реализации такого плана решений.